# initiating a string from a config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am asked to do this and I have no clue from where to start since I am new to it.

I have created a C# .NET application (a web api to be more precise) using Visual Studio 2012.

I created an lsi file ( the new version of msi files) to be able to deploy it on a server.

Now I want to create some sort of a configuration file where I can edit a string without having to go into the code every time to change it every time.

lets say the variable is called `mystring`:
1- how can I create a config file that request a string without having to go into the code?
2- how can I say the mystring=input string ?

I tried to look it up but since I don t have the exact name I don t really know what I am searching for ...

Thanks,

Comment: Check out `ConfigurationManager`/`app.config`?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to save a configuration file with the settings you want to load, I'd suggest saving it to the ProgramData folder.

I would save the settings to an XML file (or JSON) so you can serialize and deserialize the data into your program when it loads. [Guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813?wa=wsignin1.0)

You can also save other details so they'll persist each time the application is opened this way, such as a username field.